# Auto Loading XML Data Not Working with PhoneGap and iOS

Tags: ios, xml, cordova

I'm having some issues in getting some XML to load when my app does. This code works absolutely fine in a browser so the only thing I can think is that I'm doing something wrong with the phonegap `deviceready` hook.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

I've taken out my main dev server address for the xml, btw.

```
var xmlhttp;
window.onload = function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', getData, false);
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = loadData;
}

function getData() {
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://example.com/xml.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function loadData() {
    if ((xmlhttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlhttp.status == 200)) {
        var storiesXML = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("stories");
        var wrapper = '<div class="storiesWrapper">';
        var contentPage = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < storiesXML.length; i++) {
            var homeOutput = '<div class="storyContainer">';
            var titleElement = storiesXML[i].getElementsByTagName("title");
            var titleText = titleElement[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            var summaryElement = storiesXML[i].getElementsByTagName("summary");
            var summaryText = summaryElement[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            var imgElement = storiesXML[i].getElementsByTagName("img");
            var imgText = imgElement[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            var fulltextElement = storiesXML[i].getElementsByTagName("fulltext");
            var fulltextText = fulltextElement[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            var videolinkElement = storiesXML[i].getElementsByTagName("videolink");
            var videoLink = videolinkElement[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            var pageId = titleText.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '');
            homeOutput += '<img class="thumbnail" src="' + imgText + '" />';
            homeOutput += '<a class="titleText" data-transition="slide" href="#' + pageId + '">' + titleText + '</a>';
            homeOutput += '<p class="summaryText">' + summaryText + '</p>';
            homeOutput += '<div class="clear"></div>';
            homeOutput += '</div>';
            if ((document.getElementById(pageId)) == (null)) {
                var pageOutput = '<div class="pageContent" data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="' + pageId + '">';
                pageOutput += '<div data-role="header" class="header">';
                pageOutput += '<a class="backButton" href="javascript:history.go(-1)" data-transition="slide" data-diraction="reverse" data-icon="back">Back</a>'
                pageOutput += '<h1>Stories</h1>';
                pageOutput += '</div>';
                pageOutput += '<h2 class="storyTitle">' + titleText + '</h2>';
                pageOutput += '<a href="' + videoLink + '">';
                pageOutput += '<img class="featuredImage" src="' + imgText + '" />';
                pageOutput += '</a>';
                pageOutput += '<div data-role="content" class="mainText">';
                pageOutput += fulltextText;
                pageOutput += '</div>';
                pageOutput += '</div>';
                contentPage += pageOutput;
            }
            wrapper += homeOutput;
        }
        wrapper += '<div class="clear"></div>';
        wrapper += '</div>';
        document.getElementById("stories").innerHTML = wrapper;
        if ((document.getElementById(pageId)) == (null)) {
            $(contentPage).insertAfter("p#insertAfter");
        }
    }
}
setInterval(getData, 60000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem this issue was that `window.onload` triggers AFTER `deviceready`

I changed the code to this and it now works fine

```
var xmlhttp;

xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = loadData;

document.addEventListener('deviceready', getData, false);

function getData() {

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://dev.emagpress.com/app-dev/helloxml/appxml.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
```